# Sliding in fragment from bottom, pushing up existing full screen fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a UI that consists a fragment that is full-screen most of the time.  If the user takes some particular action, I want to pop in a second fragment from the bottom of the screen.  Actually, "pop in" is probably the wrong term - what I really want is to have it appear as though the initial fragment is sliding about 1/3 of the way up off the screen, while the second fragment slides in to fill that bottom 1/3.  In other words, to the user it should appear NOT that one fragment is above the other, but that they've both "slid up" some amount.

I've been experimenting with a few ways to do this.  Namely, making the second fragment's view's origin be the bottom of the screen, and then translating both views up a constant amount.  This wasn't working out elegantly.  For example, the tap recognizer seemed to not be "lined up" properly after I translated the top view.

So this makes me think I should take a step back and ask - what's the most appropriate way to do this?  Should I deal with fragments and transactions, or strictly animate view objects?

It seems the two general approaches I can take are:

1) Use layers, position the second fragment underneath the first, size it the way I want it, and then just translate the first fragment up to above the height of the second.

2) Put both fragments on the same layer, adjacent to each other, but with the second fragment off the bottom edge of the screen.  Then translate both of them upwards a constant amount.

3) Something else that I haven't thought of.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your container with the new fragment using a normal slide_up transition, it will push the current one up and off the screen.

ex:

R.id.fragment_container contains fragment A
perform a `fragment transaction` to replace R.id.fragment_container with fragment B and a custom transition, and A will slide up and off.

You can also make it slide directly over the existing fragment by having fragment A hold the fragment instead of the parent and using a child fragment.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But I don't want A to slide all the way off the screen... basically I want A to slide up, leaving about 1/3 of the bottom of the screen vacant for B.